# SaveAs 2003 word document from word 2007 VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, automation, ms-word

My system has Office2007. And i use VB.Net to automate word. Everything works fine. But when tried to save in Word2003 format(.doc), it is not working. But the saved document is readable in Word2007.

```
Dim WordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
Dim MyDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

'.....

MyDoc.SaveAs("c:\test.doc")
```

This saves the document with the filename as `test.doc`. But it won't open in Word2003. But opens flawlessly in Word2007.

How to save the document in 2003 format ?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly set the document type: it's not enough to just use the doc extension.

Comment: thank you. Can you please tell me how to set it ?

Comment: Don't have access to word right now.  Have you tried recording a macro and looking at the generated code?

Comment: No i didn't. I have never used macro before. So don't know how to perform that. From further searching in google, I found that the second parameter for SaveAs() could be the solution. But I couldn't find the wdSaveFormat constants anywhere. Reference: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/07/07/use-the-vba-saveas-method-in-excel-2007.aspx

Comment: In word press alt+F11 to open the vb editor.  Then press F2 to open the object browser.  You can search for wdSaveFormat and find the value you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From macro recorded in 2010:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="abc.doc", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238158(v=office.12).aspx, which gives the value for wdFormatDocument as 0.

Comment: Thank you. When I checked MSDN(previously), a page that shows the constants(no values) were shown. This page contains both constant names and its corresponding values. So what if I want to save the document in default Word2007 format ? Avoid the optional second argument ?

Comment: There is more than one format for 2007 and 2010, so here are some notes : http://www.rondebruin.nl/saveas.htm - Excel, but relevant, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2445060. I may get back to this if I have time, or you may find info elsewhere. Note that recording macros is really helpful.

Comment: I have tried saving the document in FileFormat number:0 . But when I tried to righclick it and select the properties-->summary-->Advanced, it shows "Normal.dotm" as template. Is that a problem ? Word2003 documents has only "Normal" as template. "dotm" seems to be for Office2007.

Comment: @Vpp Man I have not tested, but I am fairly sure it will pick up the normal template from what ever PC it is opened on.

Comment: Can you please tell me the best solution to achieve this ? I have been wasting about 2 days now, for this particular issue. :(
That 0 value is also not at all working.

Comment: @Vpp Man What exactly is the problem? I ran a little code on this PC (2010) with SaveAs2 (also available in 2007) and 0 option for file format (97-2003), I then opened the document with Office 2000 on another PC. There was almost no text, but it opened without any problems.

Comment: I have tried saving the document using Office2007, with 0 as second parameter. But the document thus generated is not readable in Office2003.

Comment: It looks like working. 0 for Word2003 and 12 for Word2007.
And I used late binding.